# Naive php web hook endpoint for use in a production environment

Tags: php

Below is the WebHook endpoint in its entirety.  I have five seconds to acknowledge if the payload is correctly formed.  After that, the payload is inserted into a queue for processing.

Importantly, it works, but it feels naive outside a Class and without any exception handling or error checking beyond the signature match. It does however, achieve exactly what I need.

Should for example, `$rawPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");` and `$authKey = $_SERVER['HTTP_SIGNATURE'];` be inside a `try` `catch` block?

Alternatively, should it be threaded in case the endpoint is flooded?

```
<?php

namespace NJIS\Helpers;

use NJIS\Helpers\XeroWebHookHandler;

$key = $_ENV['XERO_WEBHOOK_KEY'];
$rawPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $rawPayload, $key, true));
$authKey = $_SERVER['HTTP_SIGNATURE'];

if($signature === $authKey)
{
    http_response_code(200);
    XeroWebHookHandler::insertPayloadIntoDatabase($rawPayload);
}   
else
{
    http_response_code(401);
}
```

Comment: Just before I write an answer is this just a file on the webserver ? E.G on apache your document root is /var/www/someFolder where you have a file someApi.php and you make calls to that server ? Or is a part of a larger frame work with some sort of router ?

Comment: This is a file on a web server.  I was originally using a router, however the endpoint is extraordinarily strict and denied responses containing session cookies and other junk that was bundled into the http response.  Further -the endpoint didn't seem to like the way Swing handled response codes.  Because of this, .htaccess redirects to this file before any of the routing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Only several years late, but since someone bumped the question let's actually answer it. This code does look somewhat reasonable, but it should be programmed more defensively to avoid situations where people can insert anything in your queue.

### Handle all possible outputs

`hash_hmac` can return a string or the boolean `false`. You pass this directly to `base64_encode`, which will happily turn `false` into an empty string.

```php
var_dump(base64_encode(false)); // string(0) ""
```

Currently, `hash_hmac` returns `false` if the algorithm is not supported. If for some reason `sha256` is dropped as an algorithm, you can put anything in the queue with an empty signature. Adding an `!empty($signature)` check to the if-statement will allow the code to fail safely in case something odd is going on.

`file_get_contents` can return `false` on failure, and `hash_hmac` will happily treat this as an empty string for key generation. You could add a sanity check that fails early if you have nothing useful to add to the database.

### Exceptions, try and catch

None of your functions seem to throw, except maybe for `XeroWebHookHandler::insertPayloadIntoDatabase`. This also means that adding a try-catch block does not do anything useful for you. If you have a way of telling if this function fails, you can move `http_response_code` below this function and potentially return a different response code if the function fails.